# how to replace all html elements in an excel file

Tags: html, vba

I am wondering how to replace all the html elements from an excel file without naming all of them.

At this moment I am using a macro that replaces `&ecirc;` with "Ê", `&nbsp;` with " ", etc. but I have to add new values all the time.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Ok, it works for a specific cell, but how can I select an entire column let's say D and return the result in the same column?

Comment: Please remember to add your code to the question to make it more useful for other readers.

Comment: How can I replace those chars for all the sheet, not only for 1 cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSHTML can do that:

```
With CreateObject("htmlfile")
    .Open
    .write "<p> fish <em>&amp;</em> chips &hellip;"
    .Close
    MsgBox .body.outerText '// fish & chips …
End With
```

Example

```
Sub MyCode()

    '// put some html in A1
    Range("A1").Value = "<p> fish <em>&amp;</em> chips &hellip;"
    
    '// put the html as text in B1
    Range("B1").Value = getPlainTextFromHTML(Range("A1").Value)

End Sub

Function getPlainTextFromHTML(html As String)
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .Open
        .write html
        .Close
        getPlainTextFromHTML = .body.outerText
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hoe can I integrate this in my code? Or I need a separate sub?

Comment: Wrap it in a function as above.

Comment: Ok but if I want to do this for all the rows in a column, I tried Set thisWbs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastRow = thisWbs.Range("F" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = thisWbs.Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Value = getPlainTextFromHTML(Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Value) but i think something is wrong